# For loop python invalid syntax

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

i'm trying to run this loop in my program to calculate the average of H
I need to calculate value's of 2 arrays for each element of those arrays and then add them up.

```
 Htot = 0
 for i in range (0, len(redshift)):
 H = ((300000*redshift[i])/(np.power(10, (appmag[i]-19.0+5)/5))
 Htot = Htot + H

 Hgem = Htot/len(redshift)
 print Htot
```

But I get an invalid syntax error at Htot = Htot + H

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close a parenthesis on the previous line.

There are too many anyway, these are enough:

```
H = 300000 * redshift[i]  / np.power(10, (appmag[i] - 19.0 + 5) / 5)
```

Comment: Oh.. I feel so stupid now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is in the 3rd line u didnt close the brackets at the end of the       line copy this code and execute it

```
Htot = 0
for i in range (0, len(redshift)):
    H = (( 300000 * redshift[i] ) / ( np.power(10, (appmag[i] - 19.0 + 5) / 5) ))
    Htot = Htot + H
Hgem = Htot/len(redshift)
print Htot
```